# count the amounts / number generated from mysqli /PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a form where I give start and end date for chosen invoices and generate a XML with data of these invoices.

I want to at the end of this XML counting some of amounts and  the number of invoices who was generated.

For example: I choose 01.12.2018 as start and 31.12.2018 as end date of invoices. My function pull from MySQL database information about 7 invoices which fall on these dates.. The data is for example the amount of each invoice one by one. I want to have at the end of my XML file a summary of a pulled invoices - number and the amount of all generated invoices.

My code:

```
$header = $dom->createElement('Header');
for($i=1; $i<count($array); $i++) {
   $arrayAmount = $array[$i]['amount'];
   $invoice = $dom->createElement('Invoice');
   $invoice->appendChild($CountAmount   = $dom-> 
   createElement('AmountInvoice', $arrayAmount) );
   $allInvoices = $dom->createElement('AllInvoices');
   $allInvoices->appendChild($allInvoices = $dom-> 
   createElement('AllAmountInvoices', **$amountInvoices**) );
   $allInvoices->appendChild($allInvoices = $dom-> 
   createElement('NumberOfInvoices', **$numberOfInvoices**) );
}
```

The **variables with stars** are space where my function will be show the amount and number of invoices.

I try do something like that:

```
$amountInvoicesSQL = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM INVOICES WHERE issue_date BETWEEN ? AND ?");
$amountInvoicesMYSQL = mysqli_fetch_assoc($amountInvoicesSQL);
$amountInvoices = $amountInvoicesMYSQL['amount'];
```

Do you have any idea? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily keep a running total of the amount and the number of invoices is just the same as the control in your `for` loop...

```
$header = $dom->createElement('Header');
$total = 0;
for($i=1; $i<count($array); $i++) {
    $arrayAmount = $array[$i]['amount'];
    $invoice = $dom->createElement('Invoice');
    $invoice->appendChild( $dom-> createElement('AmountInvoice', $arrayAmount) );
    $total += $arrayAmount;
}

$allInvoices = $dom->createElement('AllInvoices');
$allInvoices->appendChild( $dom-> createElement('AllAmountInvoices', $total ));
$allInvoices->appendChild( $dom-> createElement('NumberOfInvoices', count($array) ));
```

You shouldn't be adding the totals in on each loop, just once at the end of the loop.  But I'm not sure where you are adding these into `$header` at all.

Also note that I've removed the way you assign to a variable when you create the element

```
   $allInvoices->appendChild($allInvoices = $dom-> 
       createElement('NumberOfInvoices', **$numberOfInvoices**) );
```

becomes

```
   $allInvoices->appendChild($dom-> createElement('NumberOfInvoices', **$numberOfInvoices**) );
```

Comment: Number of Invoices works fine, but all amount of invoices don't. Your code show me only amount of the last invoice.

Comment: Are you sure you have the + in `$total += `?

Comment: Yes. But okey, I resolved it alone. Instead += $arrayAmount; I added = ($arrayAmount + $total); and it works fine :)